# Python - Socket Error 10054 - How to prevent terminal from preventing error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, printing, terminal

Since it is not an execution-fail error, I am not sure what my options are to keep this error from popping up. I do not believe it really matters what my code is that is causing the error if there is some universal command to suppress this error line from printing see my error here

[image]

It is simply using whois to determine if the domain is registered or not. I was doing a basic test of the top 1,000 english words to see if their .com domains were taken. code here

Here is my code:

---

```
for url in wordlist:
    try:
       domain = whois.whois(url)
       boom.write( ("%s,%s,%s\r\n"% \
       (str(number), url, "TAKEN")).encode('UTF-8'))
    except:
       boom.write( ("%s,%s,%s\r\n"% \
       (str(number), url, "NOT TAKEN")).encode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: We can't guess where that exception is coming from, or what's printing it. Please show us the code you're running. If you can, try to make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue without being too long or complicated.

Comment: updated with code. any help appreciated. I believe it is printing this because of a timeout issue with whois limitations but I should still be able to just supress it printing, right?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to know for sure without your code, but wrap the section that's generating the error like this:

```
try:
    # Your error-generating code
except:
    pass
```